# POST method in Angular using a voice command as the input

Tags: angularjs, post, annyang

I have a curl command...

`"curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value":1}'` http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/Variable_ID/values/?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

I am able to post this via command line however, want to translate this into angularJS. Is there any way of doing it?

I have it so that when a certain voice command is called, I want to post this data to the url provided

The code is:

```
AnnyangService.addCommand('Go to Sleep', function($http) {
    console.debug("Ok, going to sleep...");
    setFocus("sleep");
    //window.alert("hello");
    $http({
        url: 'http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/572ec449762542669c750f77/values/?token=NrYUMnW0Ug4xF5eiyHs5tVucuZWAtY%27',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {value: "0"}
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show your angular code.

Comment: AnnyangService.addCommand('Go to Sleep', function($http) {
                console.debug("Ok, going to sleep...");
                setFocus("sleep");

                //window.alert("hello");
                $http({
                    url: 'http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/572ec449762542669c750f77/values/?token=NrYUMnW0Ug4xF5eiyHs5tVucuZWAtY',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {value: "0"}
                });
            });

Comment: Sorry if the formatting is horrible... not sure how to do it. I am complete newbie at this...

Comment: So...what is not working/the problem?

Comment: I guess I am not sure if that is the right syntax? I see no response on their GUI when I say the annyang command. I was expecting it to log a 0 1 depending on the command I run. Not sure if this would suffice the requirement?

Comment: This is resolved, I took out $http form the input as a parameter and added it as a input type in the main function for the .js file.